# How I can create layout something like in image for Android?

Tags: android

How I can create a responsive layout with element which is show in image?

[image: look at the picture]

This one page.

Comment: Really, I didn't got your question. Please describe.

Comment: divide your layout into three by using android:layout_weight

Comment: please show me ? i am new in android development

Comment: Check my answer and tell further modification if any .happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Some Text"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#C0C0C0">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00FF00"></RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]